# How can I sync my dokku application inside a vagrant box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, dokku

I am trying to run dokku inside vagrant bento/ubuntu-16.04 box. I've followed the setup instructions in dokku and set the application. However when I start to develop the need for committing and then deploying everytime I make a change is a pain.

Is there a way to sync dokku application root like a docker volume and sync whenever I change something ?